# comparing two variables using condition operator in Makefiles

Tags: linux, makefile, comparison-operators

Below is my Makefile. I just want to do a comparision using && operator (or its equivalent)
as shown in the following pseudocode.I want to run the following logic inside the "all" target

```
#   if (CUR_PI_VERSION == LAST_PI_VERSION) && (CUR_GIT_VERSION == LAST_GIT_VERSION) 
#       print "everything matched. Nothing to do"
#   else
#       print "files not matched"
#       run python script.
#
#   How do I achieve this.
```

I have looked at other answers, but I couldn't get to the result I wished.
I have attached my sample code for reference.

```
CUR_PI_VERSION:= "abc"
CUR_GIT_VERSION:= "cde"

LAST_PI_VERSION:= "abc"
LAST_GIT_VERSION:= "cde"

$(info $$CUR_GIT_VERSION is [${CUR_GIT_VERSION}])
$(info $$CUR_PI_VERSION is [${CUR_PI_VERSION}])

$(info $$LAST_GIT_VERSION is [${LAST_GIT_VERSION}])
$(info $$LAST_PI_VERSION is [${LAST_PI_VERSION}])

all:

# The pseudocode of what I want to do is as follows 
#   if (CUR_PI_VERSION == LAST_PI_VERSION) && (CUR_GIT_VERSION == LAST_GIT_VERSION) 
#       print "everything matched. Nothing to do"
#   else
#       print "files not matched"
#       run python script.
#
#   How do I achieve this.
#
    ifeq ($(CUR_GIT_VERSION),$(LAST_GIT_VERSION))
        ifeq ($(CUR_FPI_VERSION),$(LAST_FPI_VERSION))
            echo "Everything matched, so don't need the make top"
        endif 
    endif
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
all:
ifeq ($(CUR_PI_VERSION)@$(CUR_GIT_VERSION),$(LAST_PI_VERSION)@$(LAST_GIT_VERSION))
    echo "Everything matched, so don't need the make top"
endif
```

Above test compares two concatenated strings (joined by `@`):

```
$(CUR_PI_VERSION)@$(CUR_GIT_VERSION)
```

and

```
$(LAST_PI_VERSION)@$(LAST_GIT_VERSION)
```

Comment: Thanks @Philippe, could you please explain a bit on what is happening under the hood.